# set last increment id as session value in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hoe to set last increment id as session value in codeigniter. My codes are given below i got a last increment id but set a session with variable that is not working

```
    $emp_name=$_POST['emp_name'];
    $emp_housetype=$_POST['emp_housetype'];
    $emp_mobile=$_POST['emp_mobile'];
    $emp_email=$_POST['emp_email'];
    $emp_curraddress=$_POST['emp_curraddress'];


   $data=array(
   'emp_name'=>$emp_name,
   'emp_housetype'=>$emp_housetype,
   'emp_mobile'=>$emp_mobile,
   'emp_email'=>$emp_email,
   'emp_curraddress'=>$emp_curraddress
        ); 

    $this->db->insert('employees',$data); 
    $last_id=$this->db->insert_id(); 

    $empl=$this->session->set_userdata($last_id); 
    echo $empl;exit();
```

I want a session variable with printable(echo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You are not setting session properly :

```
    //In codeigniter,
    //To set session: 
    $this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');

    //to get specific session value :
    $some_name= $this->session->userdata('some_name');

   //to get all session value :
    $all_data = $this->session->userdata();
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
//for your code, need to update like this :

$this->session->set_userdata('last_id',$last_id); 
$empl = $this->session->userdata('last_id');
echo $empl;exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//In codeigniter, To set session: 
$this->session->set_userdata('variable_name', 'variable_value');

//to get session variable value :
$some_name= $this->session->userdata('variable_name');
```

//to get all session variable value :
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata();